# Do I need some kind of IE 6 hack for my page layout?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser, positioning

My site [roofcommunityservices.org](http://roofcommunityservices.org/index.html) I am being told has some div shifting issues in IE6. We do not have IE6 here at the office, but I do use the Firefox render tool to view a screenshot si I get the general idea. I am on a Mac and can't see the same issues as my client.

Could someone take a look at the site in IE6 PC and tell me what they are seeing, particularly on the donation page?

Thanks much.

Comment: extended answer with links to flash tips for XHTML.

Answer (score 4):

You can see all kinds of browser setups by using [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/)

There is some shifting on the donations page.

Also, transparent .png files are not supported in IE6.

Comment: I actually found a png fix at http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/
Works great!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it in IE6, I don't have that either. But Generally the first thing I do when trying to see why something isn't working is run it through a validator.   Sadly, your page really doesn't work well on a validator, and it runs lots of complaints.

Stating "XHTML Strict" and then using non-strict html really isn't a very sensible idea.

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Froofcommunityservices.org%2Fdonations.html

If you are lucky, fixing your 226 validation errors might help IE6.

People who disagree with me, try changing the closing tag of "title" to "titel" , and see the miracle occur where IE renders a completely white page but firefox doesn't mind.

As for getting Flash elements to validate, see here:

http://latrine.dgx.cz/how-to-correctly-insert-a-flash-into-xhtml
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashsatay

This has also been useful in the past, but its a bit dated now:

http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/

Comment: Thanks, I really need to keep that in my "to do" list when designing. The validator has helped me numerous times. I changed the doc type to fix some of the issues, the others seem to have to do with the embedded flash movie. Now to figure that out!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://www.stalebrew.com/2008/browsers/stand-alone-internet-explorer-6/
You can download a stand-alone version of Internet Explorer 6 for doing such testing.

Another option is to use http://browsershots.org to see screenshots of your website with various OS and browser options.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was fine except for the banner you had at the top. When I checked in ff, all the sub-links were available. When I checked in IE6, none of them were shown.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your navigational menu is missing entirely in IE 6.

http://tinypic.com/r/35l7pc6/5

Answer (score 0):

It might be prudent to have a virtual machine running XP with IE6 for testing your layouts.  And, as other have mentioned, running your website through a validator (w3) and solving those validation errors can give you a good starting point with pinpointing some random display issues.  Particularly if you have a lot of non-closed tags.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solutions already mentioned, there's a javascript library called IE7 (nowdays also IE8), that claims to solve IE6 ja IE7 related CSS/PNG-problems. In my experience, it does solve some, but not all of them. It's very easy to use, you just need to include the javascript file.
http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Here's some basic info about running windows on Intel Macs. 
http://www.macwindows.com/winintelmac.html

Microsoft provides images of XP SP2 with IE6 and IE7 for free (for testing purposes). See http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/11/30/ie6-and-ie7-running-on-a-single-machine.aspx

There's a handy program called IEtester (only for windows i'm afraid, but remember the virtualisation/bootcamp) that helps you see your pages in IE5.5, 6, 7 and 8.
http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score -1):

FORGET ABOUT IE6

we're already on IE8, people. it's like supporting IE4 when IE6 came out...

Comment: Reword it. you have the right point, but you say it wrong. +1 because I know where you're comming from and know it is really the only way forward.

Comment: Unfortunately, IE6 still has quite a large installed base, especially if we focus on business users. This story was posted on /. just this week: http://slashdot.org/story/09/06/02/134224/Internet-Explorer-6-Will-Not-Die

Comment: It depends entirely on your target audience. If you can get away with it, drop IE6 support and convince others to adopt something  better.

Comment: every time you fail to convince somebody to upgrade, ten more people say that we need to keep supporting legacy. If you can get people to recursively complain every time supporting IE6 is mentioned, then we win. Complain.

Comment: @Jason: That doesn't fix OP's issue. I'm glad you feel comfortable cutting off 41% of your customer base, but many devs work at companies who still mandate IE6, where it's a political fight to get software upgrades approved and coordinated, and in the meantime, they have to support everyone who needs access to their site.

Comment: Get it usable in IE6 (i.e. nav menu shows up, text isn't overlapping pictures, crap like that). If it looks a bit funky, don't worry too much about it.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. I'll work on getting it ie6 usable. My response to all comments is drop ie completely, that way us web designers don't have to put in overtime! All other browsers including Safari and Opera always display as they should.

Comment: @Adam V - I'm not cutting them off. They're still more than welcome to come to my website. They should just understand that their experience is going to be tantamount to the quality of browser they're using.

Comment: @Jason I've generally found that if your page validates, it isn't difficult to gracefully degrade for IE6. There might be some minor issues, and I'm not saying you should *support* it; recommend, STRONGLY, that users upgrade, and give them some compelling reasons to do so (some nifty features that only work in IE, but aren't essential to the use of your application). I'm saying that you should TEST in IE6, and make sure that the site isn't totally broken. It doesn't have to be perfect, just... well... not completely broken.

Comment: i would agree w/that statement. however, i would put no more than maybe 5 minutes into trying to make a site work w/ie6. if you can make it work in 5 mins, great. if not, you're wasting your time.

Comment: @Jason That depends what your customers are using. Don't punish them for using an old browser; reward them for using a modern browser.